# How to convert this code to proper float format

Tags: django

I am working on a django app to print the cost of daily expenses
I want to print the sum of the total expenses in proper format.

I used the below code to print the total

```
total_expense = Expenses.objects.aggregate(total_price=Sum('cost'))
```

and this too

```
Expenses.objects.aggregate(Sum('cost'))
```

They print the total in this format : {'total_price': Decimal('3581360')}

I want to print only **3581360**

Please can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Did you _try_ rendering it in the template? It renders as it's proper string representation in the template `3581360` as you want it to...

Answer (score 0):

**aggregate** on queryset will return result in form of a dictionary. In your case total_expense will be dictionary and total_price will be the key, you can easily access the value by a key as we do in dictionary.

```
total_expense = Expenses.objects.aggregate(total_price=Sum('cost'))
```

When you print total_expense  it will print whole dictionary which is current scenario i.e:

```
print(total_expense)
{'total_price': 116173}
```

You can get the value of sum calculated by using **total_expense ['total_price']**

```
print(total_expense ['total_price'])
116173
```

**Note :** As extension to this You can also pass sum value to a template in context and by template filter tags you can achieve more formatted results.